# New Excel issue

Tags: excel, date, validation, real-time-updates

MY work project is expanding and I have a new column that I hope is able to be date dependant on another column. Previously I got great assistance on this same excel sheet.

I have column A that needs to be 42 days minus column G.

I used the same IF formula I had in column H assuming it would work. unfortunately, it does nothing.

I included 2 screenshots of my issue along with a formula screenshot.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does that formula output that is in error?

Comment: When I plug in the formula it just sits there exactly like the pic.

Comment: Then your column is most likely set to text.

Comment: I totally overlooked that, thank you. I seriously need a vacation but this project is pushing a deadline but they keep adding to it. Thank you again.